# How to extract title and meta description using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser?

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom, simpledom

How can I extract a page's `title` and meta `description` using the [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)?

I just need the title of the page and the keywords in plain text.

Comment: The PHP library http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ I presume?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just took a look at the HTML DOM Parser, try:

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file('xxx'); //put url or filename in place of xxx
$title = $html->find('title');
echo $title->plaintext;

$descr = $html->find('meta[description]');
echo $descr->plaintext;
```

Comment: This code does not work for me (anymore? --- the answer is older than the latest version of the library), because find may return more than one element. To get it working I need to add a second parameter with a value of 0 to find: $html->find('title', 0)->plaintext;

Comment: the answer is incorrect - see my tested answer below

Answer (score 22):

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file('some_url'); 

//To get Meta Title
$meta_title = $html->find("meta[name='title']", 0)->content;

//To get Meta Description
$meta_description = $html->find("meta[name='description']", 0)->content;

//To get Meta Keywords
$meta_keywords = $html->find("meta[name='keywords']", 0)->content;
```

NOTE: The **names** of meta tags are casesensitive!

Comment: Spot on. +1 for grabbing by tag and attribute.

Answer (score 6):

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file('http://www.google.com'); 
$title = $html->find('title',0)->innertext;
```

`$html->find('title')` will return an array

so you should use `$html->find('title',0)`, so does meta[description]

Answer (score 4):

Taken from LeiXC's solution above, you need to use the simple html dom class:

```
$dom = new simple_html_dom();
$dom->load_file( 'websiteurl.com' );// put your own url in here for testing
$html = str_get_html($dom);
$descr = $html->find("meta[name=description]", 0);
$description = $descr->content;
echo $description;
```

I have tested this code and yes it is case sensitive (some meta tags use a capital D for description)

Here is some error checking for spelling errors:

```
if( is_object( $html->find("meta[name=description]", 0)) ){
    echo $html->find("meta[name=description]", 0)->content;
} elseif( is_object( $html->find("meta[name=Description]", 0)) ){
    echo $html->find("meta[name=Description]", 0)->content;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$html->find('meta[name=keywords]',0)->attr['content'];
$html->find('meta[name=description]',0)->attr['content'];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file('xxx'); 
//put url or filename in place of xxx
$title = array_shift($html->find('title'))->innertext;
echo $title;
$descr = array_shift($html->find("meta[name='description']"))->content;
echo $descr;
```

Comment: yes! tested this code .  [look myblog](http://softuses.com/how-to-extract-title-and-meta-description-using-php-simple-html-dom-parser)

Comment: I get a warning: Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference

Answer (score 1):

you can using php code and so simple to know. like here

$result = 'site.com';
$tags = get_meta_tags("html/".$result);

Comment: this function fails horribly in some cases

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is:

```
$html = str_get_html($html);
$descr = $html->find("meta[name=description]", 0);
$description = $descr->content;
```

The above code gets html into an object format, then the find method looks for a meta tag with the name description, and finally you need to return the value of the meta tag's content, not the innertext or plaintext as outlined by others.

This has been tested and used in live code. Best

Comment: Which var should hold the web URL?

Answer (score 0):

I found the easy way to take description

```
$html = new simple_html_dom(); 
$html->load_file('your_url');
$title = $html->load('title')->simpletext; //<title>**Text from here**</title>
$description = $html->load("meta[name='description']", 0)->simpletext; //<meta name="description" content="**Text from here**">
```

If your line contains extra spaces, then try this

```
$title = trim($title);
$description = trim($description);
```